# How can I import an external python file in django without raising errors in views.py

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on my website, which is a translator which you input a phrase and it gets translated into my own language. However, it is raising errors because it is not detecting the import.

Here's the code of the translator function:

```
def translator(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "a":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "U"
            else:
                translation = translation + "u"
        elif letter.lower() in "t":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "A"
            else:
                translation = translation + "a"
        elif letter.lower() in "c":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        elif letter.lower() in "g":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "C"
            else:
                translation = translation + "c"
    return translation
```

However, I am stuck in showing this funcion in my web, here's the code in views.py, here’s where the problem is shown

```
from .translate import translator

def translator_view(request):
    
    return render(request,'main/translator.html')

def translated_view(request): #here is the main problem
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    print('text:', text)
    translate = translator 
    dt = translator.detect(text)
    tr = translated.text
    context = {
        'translated': tr
    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```

I knows the solution, please answer this post because I'm genuinely stuck

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def translated_view(request): #here is the main problem
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    context = {
        'translated': translator(text)
    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```